# prevent Flask app from forcing browser to wait for background process

Tags: javascript, python, flask, python-multithreading

I run the following flask app on local host. I then hit the app on address/place_job/ with a http request. afterwards i go on my browser and look up address/track_site/job/0

**expected behavior:** The word "foo" show up immediately.

**actual behavior:** The browser (edge / Chrome) waits / spins until the thread finishes, and then immediately displays the word foo

**Question:** Why is the actual behavior happening, instead of the expected behavior, and how do i fix it? Preferably without sorting to celery or the likes.

I don't understand why this happens.  What really bugs my mind, is that the expected behavior occurs If i **delete the <script> line**  in the .HTML file. I have tested it with threading.Thread, as well as the threadpool executor from the flask-executor package.

**minimal_app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from threading import Thread
from time import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def func():
    print("started")
    start_time = time()
    while time()-start_time<20: pass
    print("ended")

@app.route('/place_job/')
def place_job():
    Thread(target=func).start()
    return "OK"

@app.route('/track_site/job/0')
def track_job():
    return render_template('minimal_template.html')
```

**static/templates/minimal_template.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <h1 id="id1"> Job Page </h1>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/const.js"></script>
        <p id="id2"> foo </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**static/js/const.js**

```
const x = 0;
```

**edit**

Below is the flask log after requesting /place_job/ and afterwards navigating to /track_site/job/0 :

```
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 20:15:04] "GET /place_job HTTP/1.1" 308 -
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 20:15:04] "GET /place_job/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
started
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 20:15:12] "GET /track_site/job/0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ended
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Apr/2022 20:15:24] "GET /static/js/const.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: Python GIL, maybe?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem regarding python GIL? the Thread.start() runs async as expected.  Note also that if i remove the line 
"   <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/const.js"></script>" from the html line the page loads immediately, even though the thread background process still runs.

Comment: How are you running the server? Any chance that it's not running as threaded, so it will handle only one request at a time? There's a config option like `threaded=True` somewhere for that (one request is the http request, retrieving the JS file is the second one)

Comment: I see. I run it threaded. Tested both running app.run(threaded=True) and run it threaded from cmd line. But it could look like the http request retrieving the js file is blocked. I will edit the answer with the output from the flask app.